# What are the possible results of PDO::getAttribute(PDO::ATTR_CONNECTION_STATUS)

Tags: php, pdo, connection

I have been looking in to this almost all day.. and can't seem to find the values returned anywhere. Can somebody tell me:

1. What values do `PDO::getAttribute(PDO::ATTR_CONNECTION_STATUS);` return?
2. Is it possible to rely on its result to determinate if the connection is still alive?(And eventually, what could I use to check if the connection is still alive?)

Comment: The question is interesting by itself but, in practice, it's probably easier to just launch the query and capture the exception.

Comment: For my implementation I would want to use `isConnected()` and if false will trigger a connect method. I do not want to replace PDO with MySQLi .. just because `mysqli::ping();`. And just out of curiosity =)

Comment: I agree with Álvaro G. Vicario totally! BUT if I understood it right the attributes are dependet of the database-driver so I guess it depends on which database/version you are talking about. Answer 1: answer from database if success, if unsuccess NULL. Answer 2: I would say it depends on which db-driver...

Comment: Actually with active connection to Mysql on localhost it returned: `localhost via TCP/IP`, what will happen if the connection dies. And I would like to implement this functionality because I store the parameters for the connection and if it is dead I could reconnect and prevent the script from throwing exception and do what it gotta do =D

Comment: Take a look at this... http://terenceyim.wordpress.com/2009/01/09/adding-ping-function-to-pdo/   Someone answered "$db->getAttribute(PDO::ATTR_CONNECTION_STATUS) keeps replying “Localhost via UNIX socket” even after stopping mysqld". I can't confirm it and it was several years ago...

Comment: the funny thing is that this is a myth. Just tested `PDO::__construct();` returns null if the connection is not made and therefor when I try to print `$lnk->getAttribute();` I get a few errors but thats it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally! it turns out that the `mysqli::ping()` function could be implemented within PDO as follows:

```
class PDOExtended extends PDO {
    public function __construct($dsn, $user, $pass, $options = array())
    {
        $this->link = parent::__construct($dsn, $user, $pass, $options);
        $this->link->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION)
    }

    // some methods

    public function isConnected()
    {
        try {
            return (bool) $this->link->query('SELECT 1+1');
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    //some other methods
}
```

**REASON:**
`PDO::query();` returns array containing the results or false, In the current case it won't return nothing, cuz the connection is dead and PDO should throw an exception at us. And that is what we are expecting. The catch block will return false and and will not stop the execution of our script. The query used

> SELECT 1+1;

will return 2 always and it is good to rely on due to the fact that it is calculated on the DB side. No connection, no result! It is not an overkill because it is very simple query and most of the databases (on normal shared host) are on localhost it will not take more than `0.0000s` which is not much of a performance issue. Have not tested it with transactions yet, but should do the trick still.